# Smooth onclick z-index change in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made this script to change z-index of one div by clicking on button, and it works. (Maybe I got mistakes in it, I'm learning). 
But z-index changes fast, and I want smooth fade out animation. How can I do it?

```
$("#card").click(function(){
    $("#info").css('z-index', -2000)('position', 'relative');
    $("#map").css('position', 'absolute');
});
```

Comment: Create a fiddle with minimal working code.

Comment: What exactly to you want to animate smoothly? The z-index is not a continous value. A `div` can be under another one, or above it, but there is no intermediate state.

Comment: [link](http://finopar.com.au/contact) something like this. (I can't make working code on fiddle :(

Comment: Chain it with jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `div` with a higher `z-index` to also have some transparency, and increase the transparency with an animation when clicking on the button, with the final result that the once above `div` ends up under. If that is correct, two css properties will need to be modified: the `z-index` and the `opacity`.

Using the names of your example, here is you can do it. I am assuming the below HTML:

```
<button id="card">Swap</button>

<div id="map"> </div> <!-- Under at first, to move up on click -->
<div id="info"> </div> <!-- Above at first, to move down on click -->
```

Both the `div`s are positionned in a way that they overlap, for example with these CSS properties:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
}
#map {
    z-index: 5;
}
#info {
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: .8;
}
```

Then the event handler you need to write to achieve the effect described above is:

```
$('#card').on('click', function() {
    $('#info').animate({opacity: 0}).css({'z-index': 5});
    $('#map').css({'z-index': 10});
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle illustrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/r7jh84nv/1/

Note that if you look at the code of the link you provided, the `z-index` is not modified. Instead the div that has a higher index is simply hidden.